# ImageLockMode.ReadWrite not accepting file

Tags: c#, image-processing

I am trying to implement the following code which seems straightforward enough but keep getting the error "'ImageLockMode' does not contain a definition for 'bmpp' and no extension method 'bmpp' accepting a first argumentof type...."

ReadWrite seems to only give me a couple methods like CompareTo, Equals, ToString. What could cause this compilation error, i am very confused, it seems like it should work?

Thanks

```
bmpp = new Bitmap(bmpog);
BitmapData bmd = bmpp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpp.Width, bmpp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite.bmpp.PixelFormat);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change part `ImageLockMode.ReadWrite.bmpp.PixelFormat` to `ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmpp.PixelFormat`.

Comment: Ohh man, what a silly syntax error I made...thanks for showing me